# How to pass language_in to Apache Ant build task

Tags: javascript, linux, ant, antbuilder

Ant is running `jscomp` on some JavaScript files. It doesn't recognise ES6 and newer features and the task fails indicating syntax errors on `let`, etc. I found suggestions that `language_in` needs to be passed with appropriate ECMAScript version. How can I do that either on the command line or in antbuild.xml?

I'm also getting `Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar` on the command line but w/o ES6 and newer features the task completes fine.